# Can antlr4 be used to parse very large gzip compressed files?

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

I am trying to parse very large gzip compressed (10+GB) file in **python3**. Instead of creating the parse tree, instead I used embedded actions based on the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500291/can-antlr4-java-parser-handle-very-large-files-or-can-it-stream-files) answer.

However, looking at the `FileStream` code it wants to read the entire file and then parse it. This will not work for big files.

So, this is a two part question.

- Can ANTLR4 use a file stream, probably custom, that allows it to read chunks of the file at a time? What should the class interface look like?
- Predicated on the above having "yes", would that class need to handle seek operations, which would be a problem if the underlying file is gzip compressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short anser: no, not possible.

Long(er) answer: ANTLR4 can potentially use unlimited lookahead, so it relies on the stream to seek to any position with no delay or parsing speed will drop to nearly a hold. For that reason all runtimes use a normal file stream that reads in the entire file at once.

There were discussions/attempts in the past to create a stream that buffers only part of the input, but I haven't heard of anything that actually works.

Comment: Suppose I know what the structure of the file is and I can estimate max token size, max token recursion, etc. I was looking at how `InputStream.GetText` gets called and noticed small jumps back and forth. I am thinking if I can estimate how far back the parser would go I should be able to maintain a buffer (loading into buffer shouldn't be a problem, but holding "old" data seems the key) Would those be sufficient? What else might get me in this scenario?

Comment: You cannot make the parser use only a limited amount of lookahead, but you might be lucky and get away with unbuffered [character](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/UnbufferedCharStream.html) and [token](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/UnbufferedTokenStream.html) streams.

Comment: What I am thinking is that I can maintain a buffer. Lookahead will not be a problem, but to manage the memory I would need to shrink the buffer from the front from time to time. I would need to know t which point the front end part of the buffer is irrelevant. Any suggestions? Would the Token stream know when this is the case?

Comment: The char stream maintains an index into the original source. Nothing before that is relevant anymore (unless you do a lookback yourself, of course). But the unbuffered streams handle that for you, so I see no reason why you should maintain an own buffer. If the existing stream do not suffice for you (e.g. because you want to use a file mapping) then implement your own stream, model after the existing stream.